# How can I "break up" numbers into smaller pieces in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I think the title needs some explaining. I wan't to make my program break up a number into smaller bits.

For example, it would break 756 into 700, 50 and 6. 9123 would be 9000, 100, 20 and 3. Is there any way I can do this for any reasonably sized number?

Comment: How do you want the output formatted? Into an array of numbers?

Comment: You can use a combination of dividing and modulus to get your desired outputs. For example, 756 / 100 = 7, and 7 * 100 = 700. Then 756 % 100 = 56. 56 / 10 = 5, and 5 * 10 = 50. etc...

Comment: @jmancherje Yes, an array of numbers

Comment: Brad, what if all the numbers are randomly generated? Is there a way the computer can tell by itself what to do?

Comment: Well, thats part of the fun on your part. You need to figure out how large the number is, so you know what number to start dividing by. One solution is to divide by increasing values of 10 until the answer is less than 0. There are more optimal ways I'm sure. So divide by 10, then 100, then 1000, etc until the answer is less than 0.

Comment: That seems like an interesting idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/desufev/4/edit?js,console)

Here is a function that can do it:

```
function breakNumbers(num){
  var nums = num.toString().split('');
  var len = nums.length;
  var answer = nums.map(function(n, i) {
    return n + (Array(len - i - 1).fill(0)).join('');
  });
    return answer.map(Number).filter(function(n) {return n !== 0;});
}
```

Comment: Wow! Well, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton Jordan!

Comment: Definitely a fun question. I was going to offer a solution with 2 loops but I like your's better.

Comment: Also @jordan, if I put 706 as a number, it prints out [700, 0, 6]. Is there anyway you could remove the 0 if there are any so it just becames [700, 6]?

Comment: Doesn't work for decimals.  breakNumber(4.3) returns [ 400, 3 ]

Comment: Hey jordan, how could I put the broken numbers into a specific array? Currently, your code just breaks the number and puts it in an array, but I can't seem to find the name of that array.

Comment: var arr = breakNumbers(num), arr is the array in that case

Comment: Hey Jordan, this code doesn't work on IE, but works fine in Chrome/Firefox. It says "Object doesn't support property or method 'fill' " in console. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
function breakup(number) {
  var digits = String(number).split('')
  return digits.map(function(digit, i) {
    return Number(digit.concat("0".repeat(digits.length - i - 1)))
  }).filter(function(n) { return n !== 0 })
}
```

So first, we want to cast the number to a string, so we pass it into the `String` primitive like so: `String(number)`

Thus, calling the `split` method on the array and passing in an empty string (which tells it to split for every character) results in an array of the digits, i.e. `["7", "5", "6"]`

We can leave them as strings for now because it makes the next part a little easier. Using the `map` function, you can pass a function which should be called on each element in the array. Besides the first argument to this function, there's an optional second argument which is the index of the item in the array. This will turn useful in our case, since where a number is in the array indicates what place it is.

Check it out, the value returned by the function passed to map takes the current number string and `concat`s another string onto it, which is a number of repeated `"0"`s. That number is determined by looking at the parent array's length and subtracting it from the index of the current item being looped on, minus one. This is because arrays are 0-indexed in JavaScript--if we just subtracted `digits.length` from the `i` (index) for the first iteration, the values would be `3` and `0` respectively, so you'd end up with `7000` for the first value if you passed in `756`. Note also that in our return statement inside the map function, we wrap it back in a `Number` primitive to cast it back from a string.

Also, you didn't mention this, but I assume you'd rather not have numbers which equal 0 in your example. By calling `filter` on the final array before its returned, we can effectively make sure that only items which are not equal to `0` are returned. Thus, if you call `breakup(756)` you'll recieve `[700, 50, 6]`, but `breakup(706)` will give you `[700, 6]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You make a smart point with the 0 part. I'll see if I can use your code if the other one doesn't work.

Comment: Keep in mind that `String.prototype.repeat` isn't supported in Internet Explorer yet. Neither is `Array.prototype.fill` from the other poster's answer. You'll have to seek out a polyfill if you wish to use either of those methods. Alternatively, `Array.prototype.push` could accomplish the same as `fill` in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using split() to break out digits, I used a regex to tokenize the number string.  This way, we can easily handle any trailing decimals by treating a digit followed by a decimal point and any further digits as a single token.  This also makes it possible to handle digits as part of a larger string.

```
function splitNumber( number ) {
    var parts = [];
    var re = /(\d(?:\.\d*)?)/g;
    while(next_part = re.exec(number)) {
        // adjust place value
        parts.forEach( function(element, index) {
            parts[index] = 10 * element;
        } );

        parts.push( next_part[0] );
    }
    return parts.map(Number).filter(function(n) {return n !== 0});
}
```

Comment: Yeah in my solution, there would have to be another sub-function to handle decimals... nice work!